# How can I instance `Functor` for a type with two parameters?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, functor, parameterized-types

**Background.** In one of my classes we've been exploring the `Parser` monad. The `Parser` monad is typically defined as either

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])
```

Or as

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> Maybe (a, String))
```

In either case, we can instance `Parser` as a `Functor` using code that works in both cases:

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser (fmap applyF . p)
    where applyF (result, s) = (f result, s)
```

If we have a `Parser` built to return `Maybe (a, String)`, this applies `f` to the `result` if the `result` exists. And if we have a `Parser` built to return `[(a, String)]`, this applies `f` to each of the `result`s returned in the list.

We can instance `Applicative`, `Monad`, `MonadPlus`, and `Alternative` is similarly generic ways (so that they work either for `Maybe` or `[]`).

**Question.** If I parameterize `Parser` based on the type used to wrap the result, how can I instance it for `Functor` and friends?

```
newtype Parser m a = Parser (String -> m (a, String))

-- How do I instance `Parser` as a Functor if `m` is a Functor?
```

Comment: If you are willing to change your definition slightly, to `String -> m (String, a)`, I believe you can derive it automatically using the `DeriveFunctor` instance. (This is because `(,) String` itself is a functor whose `fmap` would apply the function to your value of type `a`, and functors in general (and `(->) String`, `Functor m => m`, and `(,) String` in particular) compose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can here construct a constraint that `m` should be a type that is an instance of `Functor` as well, and then `fmap` on that result:

```
instance Functor m => Functor (Parser m) where
    fmap f (Parser p) = Parser (\x -> fmap g (p x))
        where g (r, s) = (f r, s)
```

Here `g` is thus a function that performs the mapping `f` on the first element of the tuple. We thus use that `g` as a "mapping" function over the result.

This will thus work for any `m` that is an instance of `Functor`, like a `Maybe`, a `[]`, a `Tree`, etc.